# mkl_?dnscsr deprecated, what should I use?

Tags: matrix, fortran, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

MKL's routine mkl_?dnscsr to convert CSR format into dense format is deprecated.

Documentation says "Use the matrix manipulation routinesfrom the Intel® oneAPI Math Kernel Library Inspector-executor Sparse BLAS interface instead."

There's no routine to convert CSR to dense in the Inspector-executor Sparse BLAS interface documentation that I can see.

What should I use?

Comment: You mean you cannot find a routine from CSR to dense? Is the formulation in your question just a mistake?

Comment: Note [matrix manipulation routines](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/inspector-executor-sparse-blas-routines/matrix-manipulation-routines.html) in what you reference is a link to the relevant page - I assume you are looking [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/sparse-blas-level-2-and-level-3-routines/sparse-blas-level-2-and-level-3-routines-1/mkl-dnscsr.html). Does this not help you?

Comment: Also note deprecated does not mean deleted.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I can use mkl_?dnscsr to convert from CSR to dense, but the manual says it's deprecated. What should I use instead?

Comment: @IanBush Thank you. The matrix manipulation routines you reference doesn't seem to have any routine to convert CSR to dense. Am I just not finding it?

Comment: Sorry - it's not something I use at all so I can't say much more. But from the *very* little I know of CSR I would have thought it very easy to roll your own. And I repeat, deprecated does not mean deleted.

Comment: @IanBush Thanks for your help! I think there might be a documentation issue, which wouldn't be the first time with MKL....

Comment: It seems that the routine is not deprecated and there might be a discrepancy in the MKL documentation. We are looking into the same and will get back to you soon.

Comment: @Shanmukh-Intel Thanks for looking into it! I hope it is deprecated though since I find it quite horrible as it is :/

Answer (score 1):

There is no IE API available to make dense -> csr conversion, You could use mkl_?dnscsr routine. Yes, they are deprecated but they are still part of the current product version and there are no plans to remove these interfaces from the product version of MKL. So you could use the same.

Comment: Why would Intel deprecate (i.e. discourage use) of a the only routine that does something as basic as a csr<->dense conversion? Is it a documentation error that Intel is just refusing to repair?